# List of Non-Negative Integers - concatenate into largest possible nr - e.g. [1,2,5] = 521

Tags: c#

I'm following [this](https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/07/five-programming-problems-every-software-engineer-should-be-able-to-solve-in-less-than-1-hour) blog asking 
Five programming problems every Software Engineer should be able to solve in less than 1 hour

I am absolutely stumped by question 4 (5 is a different story too)

Write a function that given a list of non negative integers, arranges them such that they form the largest possible number. For example, given [50, 2, 1, 9], the largest formed number is 95021.

Now the author [posted](https://blog.svpino.com/2015/05/08/solution-to-problem-4) a answer, and I saw an python attempt too:

```
import math

numbers = [50,2,1,9,10,100,52]

def arrange(lst):
    for i in xrange(0, len(lst)):
        for j in xrange(0, len(lst)):
            if i != j:
                comparison = compare(lst[i], lst[j])
                if lst[i] == comparison[0]:
                    temp = lst[j]
                    lst[j] = lst[i]
                    lst[i] = temp
    return lst

def compare(num1, num2):
    pow10_1 = math.floor(math.log10(num1))
    pow10_2 = math.floor(math.log10(num2))

    temp1 = num1
    temp2 = num2

    if pow10_1 > pow10_2:
        temp2 = (temp2 / math.pow(10, pow10_2)) * math.pow(10, pow10_1)
    elif pow10_2 > pow10_1:
        temp1 = (temp1 / math.pow(10, pow10_1)) * math.pow(10, pow10_2)

    print "Starting", num1, num2
    print "Comparing", temp1, temp2

    if temp1 > temp2:
        return [num1, num2]
    elif temp2 > temp1:
        return [num2, num1]
    else:
        if num1 < num2:
            return [num1, num2]
        else:
            return [num2, num1]

print arrange(numbers)
```

but I'm not going to learn these languages soon. Is anyone willing to share how they would sort the numbers in C# to form the largest number please?

I've also tried straight conversion to C# in VaryCode but when the IComparer gets involved, then it causes erroneous conversions.

The python attempt uses a bubble sort it seems.
Is bubble sort a starting point? What else would be used?

Comment: Languages are, for the most part, an unnecessary concern when developing algorithms. Don't try to solve problems by jumping into code. Make a few test cases and systematically solve them with pen and paper. Transfer the process to pseudo code or a plain English description *then* code it in whatever language you're comfortable with.

Comment: I updated the title now to not be as broad. I wanted to learn from other developers and see their approach for a valid problem and there were 2 eye-opening answers for which I am grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution presented uses the approach to sort the numbers in the array in a special way. For example the value `5` comes before `50` because `"505"` (`"50"+"5"`) comes before `"550"` (`"5"+"50"`). The thinking behind this isn't explained, and I'm not convinced that it actually works...

When looking that the problem, I came to this solution:

You can do it recursively. Make a method that loops through the numbers in the array and concatenates each number with the largest value that can be formed by the remaining numbers, to see which one of those is largest:

```
public static int GetLargest(int[] numbers) {
  if (numbers.Length == 1) {
    return numbers[0];
  } else {
    int largest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
      int[] other = numbers.Take(i).Concat(numbers.Skip(i + 1)).ToArray();
      int n = Int32.Parse(numbers[i].ToString() + GetLargest(other).ToString());
      if (i == 0 || n > largest) {
        largest = n;
      }
    }
    return largest;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was a totally different to approach to anything I've seen and I learned a lot,e.g. I did not know of Take/Skip.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it by bubble sort, try this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool swapped = true;
    while (swapped)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (Compare(VALUES[i], VALUES[i + 1]) > 0)
            {
                int temp = VALUES[i];
                VALUES[i] = VALUES[i + 1];
                VALUES[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        } 
    }

    String result = "";
    foreach (int integer in VALUES)
    {
        result += integer.ToString();
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public static int Compare(int lhs, int rhs)
{
    String v1 = lhs.ToString();
    String v2 = rhs.ToString();

    return (v1 + v2).CompareTo(v2 + v1) * -1;
}
```

---

The `Compare` method compares the order of two numbers that would create the largest number. When it returns value larger than 0, that means you need to swap.

This is the sorting part:

```
while (swapped)
{
    swapped = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < VALUES.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Compare(VALUES[i], VALUES[i + 1]) > 0)
        {
            int temp = VALUES[i];
            VALUES[i] = VALUES[i + 1];
            VALUES[i + 1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

It checks to consecutive values in the array and swaps if necessary. After one iteration without swapping, the sort is finished.

Finally, you concatenate the values in the array and print it out.